# CoreML converted model won't output array

Tags: swift, swiftui, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I am new to CoreML and have a simple problem but have looked everywhere and I cannot seem to find the answer. The simplest version of my problem is this: I have a model in PyTorch which should output an array (I don't want softmax, I want to do multilabel classification and output separate probabilities for each class). I want to convert this model to an MLModel using coremltools and use it in a Swift app.

Here is a dummy model and its conversion to MLModel in Python:

```py
import coremltools as ct
import torch
from torchinfo import summary

# From pytorch: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/introyt/modelsyt_tutorial.html 
class TinyModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TinyModel, self).__init__()

        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 200)
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(200, 100)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x

def main():
    guitar_net = TinyModel()
    guitar_net.eval()

    # Trace the model with random data.
    example_input = torch.rand(100)

    summary(guitar_net, (100,))

    traced_model = torch.jit.trace(guitar_net, example_input)
    out = traced_model(example_input)

    model = ct.convert(
        model=traced_model,
        inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=example_input.shape)],
    )

    model.save("TorchModel.mlmodel")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above model should (and does in Python) output a tensor of length 100. But when I take the converted model to Xcode, Xcode says the output is just a single Float32:

[image]

In spite of this, I can run predictions on the model and even access the output as if it were an array:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreML
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
        
    var torchModel: TorchModel?
    
    init() {
        do {
            torchModel = try TorchModel(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
        } catch {
            torchModel = nil
            print(error)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, Stack Overflow!")
        .task {
            let buffer = [Float32](repeating: 0, count: 100)
            let shape: [NSNumber] = [100]
            
            guard let mlMultiArray = try? MLMultiArray(shape:shape, dataType:MLMultiArrayDataType.float32) else {
                fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. MLMultiArray")
            }
            for (index, element) in buffer.enumerated() {
                mlMultiArray[index] = NSNumber(floatLiteral: Double(element))
            }
            let input = TorchModelInput(x: mlMultiArray)
            
            guard let predictionOutput = try? torchModel?.prediction(input: input).var_10 else {
                fatalError("Unexpected runtime error. model.prediction")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that occasionally I get a memory address issue when using this code (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x13fcffff0)`). With the AddressSanitizer turned on, it crashes every time, presumably because the model expects to output a single Float32 and I am treating the MLMultiArray like a length-100 array. How can I convert the model properly so that the expected output is an array of length 100?

Comment: This could be an error in how you are building the mlmodel I am not a python coder but was having a similar issue with a custom YOLO based model. I can’t tell you how to fix it but the issue was not on the swift side it was on the python side something with max suppression and training the model when making the mlmodel. Just a clue this may or may not be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I agree it is probably something on the python side, just don't see any documentation of CoreMLTools to explain how to convert to an output array instead of single float. The incredibly inelegant workaround I've now made to make the address sanitizer error go away is to make separate single float model outputs for every element in the output array. Then on the swift side I have to access each output separately instead of as an array. Really inelegant, but works I guess.